# Proving the Inf of a given set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Given $A=\{(n-5)/4n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

I want to show the $\inf(A)=-1.$ I've claimed this and shown that $(n-5)/4n \ge -1$. I now usually use archimedian property to say that there exists an $n>5/(1-4y)$ in order to prove that $y$ can't be the $\inf(A)$ as $y>(n-5)/4n$. However, solving this gives me $y<(n-5)/4n$ instead and working backwards from the correct answer gives me $n<5/(1-4y)$ which isn't shown by the archimedian property? Can anyone help

Comment: Notice that the sequence $x_n=\frac{n-5}{4n}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{5}{4n}$ is increasing and $x_1=-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A\subset \Bbb R$ and $A$ has a least member $\min A$  then $\min A  =\inf A .$

Because $\min A$ is a  lower bound for $A$  and no $y>\min A$  can be a lower bound for $A,$

(... because if $y>\min A$ then $y$ is greater than some member of $A,$ that is, $y>\min A\in A$...)

so $\min A$ must be the largest lower bound for $A$, i.e. $\min A=\inf A .$

For the set in your Q:

$-1 \in A$ because if $n=1$ then $-1=(n-5)/4n \in A.$

If $n\in \Bbb N$ then $(n-5)/4n\ge -1$ because for any $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $$(n-5)/4n\ge-1\iff 4n\cdot (n-5)/4n\ge 4n\cdot (-1)\iff n-5\ge -4n \iff 5n\ge 5.$$

So $\min A=-1 .$